# PHP Wordpress Tax query: Looping information within an WP_Query array

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array, implode, custom-taxonomy

I am attempting to create a function to handle multiple taxonomy requirements for displaying product. I warn you this is a long post as I have shown the iterations of ideas for solutions that have not worked.

http://cheekymonkeymedia.ca/blog/using-wordpress-query-multiple-taxonomies#sthash.h7ZyhyGn.dpuf

The above link a basic sample that I am trying to model my code around.

I am using this direction because I have custom posts that have custom taxonomy's. Except I have taken the values of the array and wish to generate them as requested by the user.

An array like so is passed to the function to make a request for posts.

```
$requirements = array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' =>'category',
        'term' =>'cheese'
        ),
        array(
        'taxonomy' =>'dairy',
        'term' =>'yogurt'
        ),

        );
```

Which I was attempting to use as so but you cannot foreach within an array. This logically how I view the solution. Even though I know it is wrong.

```
function query_mult_tax($array){

$myquery['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
        foreach($array as $param){
         array(
                'taxonomy' => $param["taxonomy"],
                'terms' => $param["term"],
                'field' => 'slug',
            );
         }
);

query_posts($myquery);}
```

After some tinkering, I found that I could do the foreach outside of the array, but the only way to pass the info is in an array. However the current function always writes the query with the unneeded  array warping the needed information. Which leaves me stuck, as I do not know how to escape the unneeded array within the parent array(because I cannot loop out of it).

```
function fruit_query_mult_tax($array){
wp_reset_query();
//create the basic query
$query = array('post_type' => 'fruit',
    'tax_query' => array()
);
// create the arrays
foreach($array as $param){
     $args[]=  array(
            'taxonomy' => $param["taxonomy"],
            'terms' => $param["term"],
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => "IN",
        );
    }

$query['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    $args
);

$result = new WP_Query($query);

return $result;

}
```

The challenging part of the query dumps looking like so:

```
    [tax_query] => Array
    (
        [relation] => OR
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [taxonomy] => category
                        [terms] => cheese
                        [field] => slug
                        [operator] => IN
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [taxonomy] => dairy
                        [terms] => yogurt
                        [field] => slug
                        [operator] => IN
                    )
            )
    )
```

Instead of this which is what works.

```
[tax_query] => Array
    (
        [relation] => AND
        [0] => Array
            (
                [taxonomy] => category
                [terms] => cheese
                [field] => slug
                [operator] => IN
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [taxonomy] => dariy
                [terms] => yogurt
                [field] => slug
                [operator] => IN
            )

    )
```

Which is very close, except wrapped it is wrapped in an array. How do I escape, or format out of this? I cannot do so by foreach because I am within the parent array. I have tried `$args[0]` that only gives me the first set of rules of what could be many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering for a while long I figured it out. I needed to foreach on the tax query after it had already been built.

```
function fruit_query_mult_tax($array){
wp_reset_query();
$query = array('post_type' => 'fruit',
    'tax_query' => array()
);

$query['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
);
foreach($array as $param){
     $query['tax_query'][]=  array(
            'taxonomy' => $param["taxonomy"],
            'terms' => $param["term"],
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => "IN",
        );
    }

$result = new WP_Query($query);

return $result;}
```

Hope this helps anyone else who attempts a similar multi situation tax query